# преимущества тега div

Tags: html

Начал изучать css и html, часто замечаю, что предпочтительней используют тег div. В чем его преимущества?

Comment: Ни в чём. Если есть возможность его не использовать — не используйте

Comment: Причем здесь js, css  и react???

Comment: есть такая болезнь называется **ДИВАТОЗ** (по Вадиму Макееву) не заразитесь https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W5DgVWtitjQ с 12-ой минуты

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно вы рассматривали различные примеры кода и в них демонстрировали главное - решение не касающаяся семантики тегов в html.

В HTML присутствует семантика тегов - наименование тегов со смысловым значением, т. е. `<body>` - тело, `<nav>` - навигация, `<header>` шапка\верхушка\заголовок, `<footer>` - нижний колонтитул\подвал и т.п.

Благодаря семантике проще понимать предназначение того или иного тега, но помимо смыслового значения есть еще **ряд особенностей**. Рекомендую ознакомиться с **"Семантической версткой"**, например [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Comment: спасибо большое!